# The column name is not valid

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I get a common error that probably is easy to solve but I have no clue how. This is the message I get.

The column name is not valid. [ Node name (if any) = Extent1,Column name = Blog_BlogId ]

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.    Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:** System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: The column name is not valid. [ Node name (if any) = Extent1,Column name = Blog_BlogId ]

This is my classes representing my entities:

```
public class BlogContext : DbContext
{
    public BlogContext()
        : base("SqlCeServices")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

[Table("aspnet_Users")]
public class User
{
    [Required]
    public Guid ApplicationId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LoweredUserName { get; set; }

    public string MobileAlias { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool IsAnonymous { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime LastActivityDate { get; set; }
}

public class Blog
{
    [Key]
    public int BlogId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Editors { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    [Key]
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(200)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string Abstract { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateLastEdited { get; set; }

    public virtual User UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    public virtual Blog BlogId { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(200)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    public virtual Category ParentCategory { get; set; }

    public virtual Blog BlogId { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    [Key]
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(200)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual Blog BlogId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: When do you get the exception? What query?

Comment: It accesses Users via BlogContext and casts the collection to a List. This is done in the Index action of the standard controller scaffold.

Comment: By "cast" I actually mean that I'm using ToList().

Comment: I think you will run into problems when using EF code first and circular dependencies between Blog > Post > Blog ... etc. I suspect if you removed the reference to the `Blog` property on the `Post` object the issue will go away.

Comment: Are you using EF CF against an existing database?

Comment: The database is created when running the app and updated with the rest of the entities when doing a migration. It requires me to edit the migration files though. But it works.

Answer (score 1):

Consider changing your Post class so that BlogId references the FK to the associated Blog instead of the Blog object itself.  Add a new property Blog to reference the actual Blog object.

```
public class Post
{
    [Key]
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(200)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string Abstract { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateLastEdited { get; set; }

    public virtual User UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    public virtual int BlogId { get; set; }
    public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I had a similar issue which this fixed, adding the virtual int resolved this issue for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try...**ForeignKey** annotation

public virtual int BlogId { get; set; }

**[ForeignKey("BlogId ")]**
public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }

Answer (score 0):

Detach the connection from DB, Delete any App Data related to application and rebuild and try again, It worked for me.