# Error: The column name id is not valid from Spring Data Jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to find some records from a table using Spring Data Jpa but I keep getting error that says The column id is not valid. I have searched online for solutions like [The column name is not valid - error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31921482/the-column-name-is-not-valid-error) , [The column name is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269892/the-column-name-is-not-valid) , [Spring Data JPA "The column name Id is not valid"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50859830/spring-data-jpa-the-column-name-id-is-not-valid)  and the solutions have not helped my specific case. So I decided to ask for help here.

The error occurs when I hit the controller from postman localhost:8080//api/portal/portal-user

The get request enters the controller and stops at portal_usersRepository.findApprovedUsers(); it doesn’t enter the service class but throws that error at the point of queryin the dB.

PS: The dB table am working with is a legacy table with a lot of null columns.

Below is the entity class:

```
    @Data
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "PORTAL_USER")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
    public class Portal_User implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "ID")
        private Long id;

        @Column(name = "SURNAME")
        private String surname;

        @Column(name = "FIRSTNAME")
        private String firstname;

        @Column(name = "OTHER_NAME")
        private String otherName;

        @Column(name = "EMAIL")
        private String email;

        @Column(name = "PHONE_NUMBER")
        private String phoneNumber;

        @Column(name = "USER_ID")
        private String userId;

        @Column(name = "APPROVED")
        private Boolean approved;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "DEPARTMENT_FK", referencedColumnName = "id")
        private Department departmentFk;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "PORTAL_USER_TYPE_FK", referencedColumnName = "id")
        private Portal_User_Type portalUserTypeFk;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "MINISTRY_FK", referencedColumnName = "id")
        private Ministry ministryFk;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "AGENCY_FK", referencedColumnName = "id")
        private Agency agencyFk;

        @Column(name = "GENDER")
        private String gender;

        @Column(name = "DATE_OF_BIRTH")
        private Date dateOfBirth;

        @Column(name = "STREET_NUMBER")
        private String streetNumber;

        @Column(name = "POSTCODE")
        private String postcode;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "COUNTRY_FK", referencedColumnName = "id")
        private Country countryFk;

        @Column(name = "NATIONALITY")
        private String nationality;

        @Column(name = "ADDRESS")
        private String address;

        @Column(name = "CITY")
        private String city;

        @Column(name = "STATE")
        private String state;

        @Column(name = "LGA")
        private String lga;

        @Column(name = "ACCREDITATION_NUMBER")
        private String accreditationNumber;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "PICK_UP_LOCATIONS_FK", referencedColumnName = "id")
        private Pick_Up_Locations pickUpLocations_fk;

        @Column(name = "OCCUPATION")
        private String occupation;

        @Column(name = "IS_ACCREDITED_USER")
        private Boolean isAccreditedUser;

        @OneToOne(targetEntity = CAC_Branch_Location.class)
        @JoinColumn(name = "CAC_BRANCH_LOCATION_FK", referencedColumnName = "id")
        private CAC_Branch_Location branchLocation;

        @Column(name = "STAFF_ID")
        private String staffId;

        @Column(name = "IS_CUSTOMER")
        private Boolean isCustomer;

        @Column(name = "NIN")
        private String nin;

        @Column(name = "identityType")
        private String identityType;

        @Column(name = "PWD")
        private String PWD;

        @Column(name = "IS_A_SPECIAL_ACCESS_USER")
        private Boolean isASspecialAccessUser;

        @Column(name = "UPDATING_OFFICE")
        private String updatingOffice;

        @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
        private String password;

        @Column(name = "DATE_CREATED")
        private Date dateCreated;

        @Column(name = "EMAIL_ADDRESS_VERIFIED")
        private Boolean emailAddressVerified;

        @Column(name = "PHONE_NUMBER_VERIFIED")
        private Boolean phoneNumberVerified;

        @Column(name = "LOCKED_OUT")
        private Boolean lockedOut;

        @Column(name = "LOCKOUT_DATE")
        private Date lockoutDate;

        @Column(name = "STATUS")
        private String status;

        @Column(name = "SECRET_QUESTION")
        private String secretQuestion;

        @Column(name = "SECRET_QUESTION_ANSWER")
        private String secretQuestionAnswer;

        @Column(name = "CONTACT_ADDRESS")
        private String contactAddress;

        @OneToOne(targetEntity = Address.class)
        @JoinColumn(name = "ADDRESS_FK", referencedColumnName = "id")
        private Address addressFk;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "NATIONALITY_FK", referencedColumnName = "id")
        private Nationality nationalityFk;

        @Column(name = "USERNAME")
        private String username;

        @JsonIgnore
        @ManyToMany
        @JoinTable(name = "portal_user_role",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PORTAL_USER_FK"),
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_FK"))
        private List<Role> roles;

        @Transient
        private long noOfTasks;

        @Transient
        private AccreditationUserRequests accreditationUserRequests;

        public Portal_User() {
        }

        public Portal_User(Long id, String username, String email) {
            this.id = id;
            this.email = email;
            this.username = username;
        }

        public Portal_User(Long id, String surname, String firstname, String otherName) {
            this.id = id;
            this.surname = surname;
            this.firstname = firstname;
            this.otherName = otherName;
        }

        public Portal_User(List<Role> roles) {
            this.roles = roles;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) {
                return true;
            }
            if (o == null) {
                return false;
            }
            Portal_User user = (Portal_User) o;
            return Objects.equals(id, user.getId());
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(id);
        }

        @Transient
        public String getFullNames(){
            String fullNames = this.getFirstname();
            if (this.getOtherName()!=null && this.getOtherName().length() > 0){
                fullNames += " "+this.getOtherName();
            }
            fullNames += " "+this.getSurname();
            return fullNames;
        }

        @Transient
        public String getFullAddress2() {
            String anAddress = "";

            if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(this.address)) {
                anAddress = anAddress + this.address;
            }

            if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(this.city)) {
                if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(anAddress)) {
                    anAddress = this.city;
                } else {
                    anAddress = anAddress + ", " + this.city;
                }

            }
            if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(this.state)) {
                if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(anAddress)) {
                    anAddress = this.state;
                } else {
                    anAddress = anAddress + ", " + this.state;
                }
            }

            return anAddress;
        }
    }
```

This is my service class:

```
@Data
@Service
public class Portal_UserService {


    @Autowired
    private Portal_UsersRepository portal_usersRepository;


    public List<PortalUserDto> findPortalUsers(List<Portal_User> portal_users) {
        System.out.println("Hello SERVICE...>>>");

        List<PortalUserDto> portalUserDtoList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (portal_users != null && !portal_users.isEmpty()) {
            portal_users.stream().map(portalUserReport -> {


                PortalUserDto portalDto = new PortalUserDto();

                portalDto.setFirstname(portalUserReport.getFirstname());
                portalDto.setSurname(portalUserReport.getSurname());
                portalDto.setEmail(portalUserReport.getEmail());
                portalDto.setApproved(portalUserReport.getApproved());

                return portalDto;
            }).forEachOrdered(portalDto -> {
                portalUserDtoList.add(portalDto);
            });
        }
        return portalUserDtoList;
    }

}
```

Here is a snippet from my controller:

```
    @GetMapping("/portal-user")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> findPortalByApproved() {
        List<PortalUserInterface> portalUsers = portal_usersRepository.findApprovedUsers();
        List<PortalUserDto> userDtoList = new ArrayList<>();

        System.out.println("Hello CONTROLLER...>>>");
        if (portalUsers != null) {
            portalUsers.forEach((portalUser) -> {

                PortalUserDto userDto = new PortalUserDto();

                userDto.setFirstname(portalUser.getFirstname());
                userDto.setSurname(portalUser.getSurname());
                userDto.setEmail(portalUser.getEmail());
                userDto.setApproved(portalUser.getApproved());

                userDtoList.add(userDto);
            });

        }
            return ResponseEntity.ok(new JsonResponse("See Data Object for Details", userDtoList));

        }
```

**UPDATE**

Here is my repository:

```
public interface Portal_UsersRepository extends JpaRepository<Portal_User, Long> {

    @Query(value="SELECT FIRSTNAME, SURNAME, EMAIL FROM PORTAL_USER "
            + "WHERE APPROVED = 1 "
            + "ORDER BY ID DESC ", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Portal_User> findApprovedPortalUsers();


    @Query(value="SELECT FIRSTNAME, SURNAME, EMAIL FROM PORTAL_USER "
            + "WHERE APPROVED = 1 "
            + "ORDER BY ID DESC ", nativeQuery = true)
    List<PortalUserInterface> findApprovedUsers();
}
```

When I use  the entity in my controller like this:
`List<Portal_User> portalUsers = portal_usersRepository.findApprovedPortalUsers(); List<PortalUserDto> userDtoList = new ArrayList<>();`

I get the following error trace:

```
...SYSTEM LAUNCHED!!!
2020-09-29 21:28:01.452  INFO 32616 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-09-29 21:28:01.456  INFO 32616 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-09-29 21:28:01.468  INFO 32616 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 12 ms
Hibernate: SELECT FIRSTNAME, SURNAME, EMAIL FROM PORTAL_USER WHERE APPROVED = 1 ORDER BY ID DESC 
2020-09-29 21:28:37.894  WARN 32616 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S1093
2020-09-29 21:28:37.894 ERROR 32616 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : The column name id is not valid.
2020-09-29 21:28:37.914 ERROR 32616 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute query; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query] with root cause

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The column name id is not valid.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:234) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.findColumn(SQLServerResultSet.java:686) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getLong(SQLServerResultSet.java:2328) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getLong(HikariProxyResultSet.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BigIntTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(BigIntTypeDescriptor.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:808) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:732) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowsFromResultSet(Loader.java:1044) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:995) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:964) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:350) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2887) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2869) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2701) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2696) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2142) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1163) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:173) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1533) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.21.Final.jar:5.4.21.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:126) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:154) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:142) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor$QueryMethodInvoker.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:195) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:130) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367) ~[spring-tx-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:149) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.4.RELEASE.jar:2.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy119.findApprovedPortalUsers(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:205) ~[spring-aop-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy67.findApprovedPortalUsers(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.oasis.isds.executivedashboard.controller.PortalUsersController.findPortalByApproved(PortalUsersController.java:34) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.38.jar:9.0.38]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]

2020-09-29 21:56:23.953  WARN 32616 --- [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=14m3s351ms76µs200ns).
```

And When I use PortalUserInterface, `List<PortalUserInterface> portalUsers = portal_usersRepository.findApprovedUsers();`

I get this error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Read timed out
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:2924) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.read(IOBuffer.java:2029) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.readPacket(IOBuffer.java:6418) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.startResponse(IOBuffer.java:7579) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
```

Here is a snippet from my pom.xml

```
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
```

Please help me because this error is happening in different controllers I am using for this project. I have spent hours trying to fix it to no avail. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you add full stack trace...also try @Entity(name="Portal_User")

Comment: Please share the console logs and explain when does that error occur? Which class, which method call causes the problem etc.?

Comment: I just updated the question to provide the stack trace @Onur

Comment: I tried both @Entity(Portal_User ) and PortalUserInterface and the error trace is the update on the question above. @Alien

Comment: The error occurs when I hit the controller from postman localhost:8080//api/portal/portal-user

The get request enters the controller and stops at portal_usersRepository.findApprovedUsers(); it doesn’t enter the service class but throws that error at the point of queryin the dB. 

PS: The dB table am working with is a legacy table with a lot of null columns.

@Onur

Comment: Without spending the time to read through all this, I'll just note an observation of mine:  The error message mentions `id`, but you have `@Column(name = "ID")`.  Wondering if that's it...just a case difference problem.

Comment: What's that read timed out error? Are you sure your application is able to connect to the database? com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Read timed out at

Comment: Yes, I have run other a previous query before on this database. The read timed out error is what comes out when I use PortUserInterface to call the repository @Onur

Comment: Still we can not see what you're calling in console logs! Please share the full log where we'll be able to see the cause of the error in your own project classes, not library classes!

Comment: Folow mapping to retrive specific columns only and use interface with getters only for columns you want  try this 
@Query("SELECT new Map(" +
            "d.firstname as  firstname," +
            "d.surname as surname,"+
            "d.email as email"+
            ") FROM PORTAL_USER as d"+
            " where d.approved=1  order by d.id desc") 
            List<PortalUserInterface> findApprovedUsers();
and your interface for this file should be like this 
public interface PortalUserInterface{
    String getFirstname();

    String getSurname();

    String getEmail();
}

Comment: Thanks but I have tried this and when I did I still got the read time out error.. @Suul

Comment: I have just updated and added the complete log... thanks @Onur

Comment: Well can that be because of you are selecting only firstname, surname and email but trying to map it to a whole Portal_User object?

Comment: @OnurBaştürk is right as I mentioned above kindly follow that you should only put those columns getters in the interface which you required

Comment: Ok now let me understand, the first problem with the id column is solved?

Comment: Can you also try including the id field in select?

Comment: This is the interface I used when I got read time out... @Onur

the id problem is for when I use the entity Portal_User


public interface PortalUserInterface {

    public String getFirstname();

    public String getSurname();

    public String getEmail();

    public Boolean getApproved();

}

Comment: How long does the query take when you execute it in the database?

Comment: Sometimes more than 2 minutes @Onur

Comment: @kingified, got it. Please try putting a debug point at `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.findColumn(SQLServerResultSet.java:686) ` and see what are in the columnNames and userProvidedColumnName. Based on https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/blob/v7.4.1/src/main/java/com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerResultSet.java, it couldn't find a matching column `columns[i].getColumnName()` and threw error

Comment: @gtiwari333 when I added ID to the Query, the request takes time to send as usual and I get this error message afterwards: The column name pwd is not valid. at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:234) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.findColumn(SQLServerResultSet.java:686) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:na]
 at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getString(SQLServerResultSet.java:2503) ~[mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre8.jar:na]

Comment: @gtiwari333 PWD is one of the columns with lots NULL values all through and there are many others like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to identify the cause of this problem and fixed it, so I decided to share for the benefit of others. The approach that worked was using an interface to fetch the records. But this approach did not work initially because the database table has over 4 million records. That was why I was getting the read timed out error. I only discovered this after running my project in debug mode as I was not notified of the size of the table initially. So here is how I queried the database....

I reduced the search to TOP 5000 ... and it worked!

```
    @Query(value="SELECT TOP 5000 FIRSTNAME, SURNAME, EMAIL FROM PORTAL_USER "
            + "WHERE APPROVED = 1 "
            + "ORDER BY ID DESC ", nativeQuery = true)
    List<PortalUserInterface> findApprovedUsers();
```

Here is the interface I used for fetching the records from the repository

```
public interface PortalUserInterface {

    public Long getId();
    
    public String getFirstname();

    public String getSurname();

    public String getEmail();

}
```

This was how I solved the problem.

Thanks to all who contributed one way or the other.